# How to get a blend mode effect without use the CSS property mix-blend-mode: multiply

Tags: css, mix-blend-mode

I want to do a thing that should look like this code output, but without using the property `mix-blend-mode: multiply` of css, in order to get support for some old versions of moderns browsers.

This feature of CSS is still low supporting, look this link [caniuse.com[mix-blend-mode]](http://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode)

```css
.active{
  font-size: 80px;
  font-family: "DejaVu Sans";
  text-align: center;
  color: #646e7a;
}
.active::after {
  background: #00d7a7 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  content: "";
  height: 45px;
  left: 10%;
  margin-top: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  top: 13.8%;
}
```

```html
<div class="active">
    WEB
</div>
```

Comment: what about an `rgba(100,110,122,0.8)` value on the text? (makes the text semi-transparent)

Comment: Changing the alpha won't change the blend mode.

Comment: Thanks @marcellothearcane I have used your idea. It's true, changing the alpha won't change the blend mode, however help to get an approximation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nice solution that I have found:

```css
.active{
    background: #00d7a7 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: rgba(30, 40, 52, 0.73);
    font-family: "DejaVu Sans";
    font-size: 80px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 0.6;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="active">
    WEB
</div>
```